# How to apply vertical scroll bar to kendo listview?

Tags: listview, kendo-ui

I am using listview in some of the mvc views. When page size is increased, e.g. 50 items per page, records are coming out of the listview. To fix this issue, how to apply vertical scroll bar to kendo listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListView` itself does not provide a built-in configurable scrolling functionality, but you can enable it easily with CSS just like for a regular `<div>` element. For example:

```
#ListViewID
{
     height: 400px;
     overflow: auto;
}
```

You can also use max-height instead of height, so that the widget resizes automatically if it has a small number of items.